# Can't get rid of old bluetooth network connection in NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager, bluetooth

NetworkManager lists a bluetooth network connection I did with my smartphone long ago. I've tried `nmcli con delete` and `rm` from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` but it always comes back on NetworkManager restart. How to get rid of it? It's not on `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` anymore but it's listed by `nmcli con show`. Deleting it and restarting NM makes it reaper with a new UUID.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I just needed to unpair the device from the bluetooth list of previously paired devices in the bluetooth panel.